# Typescript static function with return type of implementing class

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, return-type

I am building a React-Native project with Typescript. I'm using Realm for opt-in cloud sync, and I built separate classes for managing local and cloud data. In order for both to be able to work generically with all my Models, I've implemented this Interface in them:

```
export default interface PersistentObject {
    id:     string
    schema: Realm.ObjectSchema

    static parseFromRealm(object: Realm.Object): 
}
```

See that empty space after the parse function? That's my problem. I need to return an object of the type that implements this interface. So if one of my data worker classes is retrieving a player, game or anything that implements `PersistentObject`, it can parse te data object to the model.

Coming from a Swift background, this seemed like a really straightforward thing to do. However it appears to be a bit more difficult in Typescript.

Does anyone know how to go about this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what the parseFromRealm function must return but I think I fixed the syntax so you can set the return type of that function anything you like.

I hope it helps

```
export default interface PersistentObject {
    id: string;
    schema: Realm.ObjectSchema;
    static parseFromRealm: (object: Realm.Object) => any;
}
```

Comment: Hi! The problem here seems to be that nothing can be defined static in an interface.. any other suggestions?